# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.app.core.Users]

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

Hi I am trying to insert record but getting the below exceptions:

```
INFO: uderId:::: 3
INFO: Hibernate: insert into users (role, department, loginid, permission, admin_power) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
SEVERE: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.app.core.Users]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at com.app.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl.save(UserDAOImpl.java:36)
    at com.app.core.UsersBean.execute(UsersBean.java:249)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.
SEVERE: doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'antrixedms.dbo.users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in anticipation...

My UserBean:

```
   UserDAO userDAO= UserDAOFactory.create();
            Users u=new Users();
            int id = userDAO.getMaxUserId();
            System.out.println("getMaxUserId:: "+id);
            RoleDAO roleDAO= RoleDAOFactory.create();
            Role r=roleDAO.getRole(this.role);

            u.setId(id+1);
            u.setRole(r);

            DepartmentDAO departmentDAO= DepartmentDAOFactory.create();
            Department d=departmentDAO.getDepartment(this.department);
            u.setDepartment(d);

            u.setLoginId(this.loginId);
            u.setPermission(Users.ACTIVE);
            u.setAdminPower(this.adminPower);
            Userinfo ui=new Userinfo();
            ui.setId(id+1);
            ui.setUserId(this.userId);
            ui.setFirstName(this.firstName);
            ui.setLastName(this.lastName);
            ui.setAddress(this.address);
            ui.setEmail(this.email);
            if(!this.mobile.equals("")){
                this.mobile=this.countryCodeMob + "-" + this.mobile;
            }
            ui.setMobile(this.mobile);
            this.telephone=this.countryCodeTel + "-" + this.telephone;
            ui.setTelephone(this.telephone);

            if(!this.fax.equals("")){
                this.fax=this.countryCodeFax + "-" + this.fax;
            }
            ui.setFax(this.fax);

            ui.setUserId(this.userId);

            CityDAO cityDAO= CityDAOFactory.create();
            ui.setCity(cityDAO.getCity(this.city));
            u.setUserinfo(ui);
            ui.setUser(u);
            try{
                userDAO.save(u);
                new ActivityLog(getUser(Integer.parseInt(this.usid)).getLoginId() , "User Creation :" +this.loginId, ActivityLog.SUCCESS,ActivityLog.ADMIN).writeLog();
                jObj.addProperty("result", "SUCCESS");
            }catch(Exception e){
                new ActivityLog(getUser(Integer.parseInt(this.usid)).getLoginId() , "User Creation :"+this.loginId, ActivityLog.FAILED,ActivityLog.ADMIN).writeLog();
                jObj.addProperty("result", "FAILED");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //new SMTPUtil().sendMail("admin@takirasolutions.com", u.getLoginId(), "User Created", "Login using ur email Id and Password");

        }
```

My Users Entity:

```
public class Users  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private Userinfo userinfo;
     private Role role;
     private Department department;
     private String loginId;
     private int permission;
     private int adminPower;
     public static final int ADMIN=1;
     public static final int ACTIVE=1;
     public static final int DEACTIVE=0;
     public static final int TERMINATED=2;
     public static final int ADMIN_POWER=1;
     public static final String DOCUMENT_ROOT ="Documents";

     private Set processDetatilsesForParentUserfk = new HashSet(0);
     private Set processDetatilses = new HashSet(0);

     public static HashMap<Integer,String> status=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
     static{
        status.put(0,"Deactive");
        status.put(1,"Active");
        status.put(2,"Terminated");
     }   

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Userinfo userinfo, Role role, Department department, String loginId) {
       this.userinfo = userinfo;
       this.role = role;
       this.department = department;
       this.loginId = loginId;
    }
```

.. getters & setters....

My Users.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 22 Aug, 2013 11:06:12 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.app.core.Users" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="userinfo" class="com.app.core.Userinfo" cascade="all">
        </one-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="role" class="com.app.core.Role" fetch="select" lazy="false">
            <column name="role" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="department" class="com.app.core.Department" fetch="select" lazy="false" not-found="ignore">
            <column name="department" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="loginId" type="string">
            <column name="loginid" length="64" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="permission" type="int">
            <column name="permission" length="1" not-null="true" default="1"/>
        </property>
        <property name="adminPower" type="int">
            <column name="admin_power" length="1" not-null="true" default="0"/>
        </property>

       <!--<set name="processDetatilses" table="process_detatils" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="fk_user" not-null="false" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.app.core.ProcessDetatils" />
        </set>-->



        <set name="processDetatilsesForParentUserfk" table="process_detatils" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="parent_userfk" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.app.core.ProcessDetatils" />
        </set>



        <set name="processDetatilses" table="process_detatils" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
            <column name="fk_user" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.app.core.ProcessDetatils" />
        </set>

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Plesse help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have configured id property of Users entity class as auto generated value

```
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
```

But you are setting the value for the property id as

```
int id = userDAO.getMaxUserId();
u.setId(id+1);
```

so remove the above two lines of code in your program to avoid constraint violation exception.

Comment: I have the same problem which has been rectified by removing the line "transaction.commit()". Any idea on this ?

Comment: If you remove the commit statement, then the data won't be persisted into the table.